# Is there a Plone 4 Users and Groups audit trail?

Tags: plone

I have successfully created a Plone 4 (`Plone 4.0.7`) Group whose sole purpose is to manage users.

Ideally we'd like an audit trail of who creates/changes users/groups on the site. Is there any existing functionality available to do this, if not would it be a difficult thing to put in place?

Answer (score 4):

This functionality is not available in Plone by default. You have to register your subscribers for proper events.
The events already available are:

- **IPrincipalCreatedEvent**: A new principal (user) has been created
- **IPrincipalDeletedEvent**: A user has been removed.
- **ICredentialsUpdatedEvent**: A principal (user) has changed his/her password

([Products/PluggableAuthService/interfaces/events.py](http://svn.zope.org/Products.PluggableAuthService/trunk/Products/PluggableAuthService/interfaces/events.py?rev=80080&view=markup))

There's not an event raised during roles changes. You have to create your own event for that and then raise it somewhere (a good point could be [plone.app.controlpanel.usergroups.py#L319](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.controlpanel/blob/master/plone/app/controlpanel/usergroups.py#L319). You'll need to override [this browserview](https://github.com/plone/plone.app.controlpanel/blob/master/plone/app/controlpanel/configure.zcml#L141))

Answer (score 0):

There is a new product called [collective.AuditLog](https://github.com/collective/collective.auditlog) that can partially answer this.

As Giacomo said earlier there is not an event raised during roles changes. However, you could use AuditLog to track when users are Added, Removed, and even when they log in and log out if you wanted. These are all done using Content Rule triggers.

And if you created your own event for roles changes, you could use that as a content rule trigger for AuditLog as well.

A little late, but hopefully this will help someone who stumbles across this question.